# Execute unobtrusive Javascript after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to use [John Resig's](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) pretty date for replacing my ugly time stamps with some nice-to-read time specification.
So I thought about using the following unobtrusive html markup:

```
 <span data-type="prettyDate">25.04.2012 10:16:37</span>
```

Acording to that I use following Javascript/jQuery to prettify the date:

```
 $(function() {
    $('[data-type="prettyDate"]').prettyDate();
 }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to deal with markup that is loaded using ajax because that would not be caught since it does not yet exist when the DOM ready event fires. Reacting to events on "ajaxed" elements is pretty easy using the [on handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/). But this is not an event.

Comment: To do this kind of things, I usually have a "checkAll" method that I call each time I load something (for example in the ajax callback).

Comment: A colleague of mine created a jquery plugin called liveReady which combines the behaviour of $.read and $.live. That is exactly what i was looking for: http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/announcing-jquery-live-ready-1-0-release/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `.prettyDate()` after each Ajax response is added to the DOM. A simple way to do that is to set a global `complete` handler with [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution with less side effects, but I guess using global ajaxComplete is the best approach.

Comment: @Towa, `ajaxComplete` is a "global" ajax event, and it's broadcast to all elements in the DOM. So you can bind it to some high level element (like `document`), only once, with `.bind` or `.on`. See [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to target dynamic content before it's actually been inserted into the document, something like:

```
success: function(html) {
   var $html = $(html);
   $html.find('[data-type="prettyDate"]').prettyDate();
   $(somewhere in document).append($html);
}
```

Comment: It could get kind of annoying to write this for every single AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do to get the best performance out of this is have a function which get called on the data as it gets returned from the ajax callback. That way you can prettify your date before adding them to the DOM.

You don't want to call pretty date on element in the DOM every time as you will process date already done too.

So, something like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url:'someurl',
  success: function(data) {
    var $content = $(data).find('[data-type="prettyDate"]').prettyDate();
    $('#mycontainer').append($content);
  }
});
```

or have an helper function which you call

```
function prettify(data) {
    return $(data).find('[data-type="prettyDate"]').prettyDate();
}
```

or even better hook into the ajax call so that it is done for all html content

Answer (score 1):

There have been a number of cases where I needed certain code to execute after every AJAX call. I'm not sure if it's considered the "correct" solution but I simply decided to create my own wrapper method and use that whenever I needed to make an AJAX request. It typically looks something like this:

```
AJAXLoadData: function (url, data, successCallBack) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Code I want to execute with every AJAX call
            // goes here.

            // Then trigger the callback function.
            if (successCallBack) successCallBack(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Server error.");
        }
    });
}
```

In my case this made it particularly convenient to create a javascript caching system for static HTML files.

Comment: Events are more suited for this, particularly http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: In some instances this may be true but you may want a technique that allows you to bypass the additional function calls in special instances. My solution would allow this easily since there's nothing stopping you from calling jQuery's $.ajax method directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate this code into your ajax success callback function.  When the ajax is done and you update your page, also run the code to prettify the dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the things [`.on()` is for](http://api.jquery.com/on/). (In the olden days, [`.live()` would have been used](http://api.jquery.com/live/).)

Comment: How ? On what event would you bind this ?

Comment: @dystroy I'd fire a custom event from the Ajax success, but whether or not that makes sense depends on the context of the app. (I tend towards behavioral abstractions so rely on sort-of a pub/sub model, but it depends on the complexity of the app. Just doing it in the `success` callback is obviously easier and more straight-forward.)